# Angular UI Router: child state loaded twice when parent and child take parameter of same name in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

http://plnkr.co/edit/B4RMbBCZKxXcJAWy5B0G

This pluncker can reproduce the issue.

I defined two states in this demo, one parent, one child.

They both take a parameter called `"someParameter"` in url.

When you go from parent state to child state by clicking the button, you can see in console, each log statement is executed twice.

Any idea why this would happen? And how do I fix it?

(PS: in my production code, I do need the parent and child page both to take a parameter of the same name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with parameter definition just on a parent state

```
.state('home.list', {
    url: '/list', //?someParameter',
```

Check the [adjusted plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0j0XAaFCZKuWOQCU4QB7?p=preview)

And that way, both, child and parent will be provided with such param, and they both will be refreshed if its value changes. Also, double console log is solved...

Answer (score 0):

You could this

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  params: {
    someParameter: ''
  },
  templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
```

Plunkr [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jA2DkrjtJudtxL8HZDkc?p=preview)

Comment: I just tried it, but this makes parent solve along with child, when I go from parent to child

Comment: Yes, so what do you expect then?